# How to ad appimage to "Open With" menu

Tags: appmenu, file-association

I installed Lightburn software appimage on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  The files created in Lightburn are saved as either .lbrn or .lbrn2 but when I navigate to these files in the file explorer they don't associate with the app.  Also, the app does not show when I right click and choose "Open With".  Is there a way I can ad this app to the "Open With" menu?

**The app is stored in:** ~/.local/share/LightBurn

**lightburn.desktop is in:** /usr/share/applications

[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=LightBurn

Comment=Better Software For Laser Cutters

Exec=/home/thinus/.local/share/LightBurn//LightBurn

Icon=/home/thinus/.local/share/LightBurn//LightBurn.png

Categories=Graphics;

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Does your `lightburn.desktop` file function, i.e., can you see it in the application overview and launch it? That file has to be correct in order to show up anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I can see it on my app grid and I have added it to my favourites.  I can open the program and access the files I want from there but I can not choose a file and open it with the lightburn program.  If that makes sence.

Comment: In the "Select Application" dialog you obtain when selecting "Open With Other Application" in the right-click menu, there is a "View all applications" button. Did you try that and is it not in the list there?

Comment: Correct.  It does not show in the "open With Other Application" even when I select "View All Applications".  That is where I would like to see it as per my oiginal question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Select Application" dialog that you obtain when selecting "Open With Other Application" in the right-click menu of a file in Files is automatically populated with `.desktop` launchers from the dedicated folders that can accept a file path on the command line. These dedicated folders include `~/.local/share/applications` and `applications` folders in the directories listed in the XDG_DATA_DIRS environmental variable.

The current command in your `.desktop` file does not suggest that the program can take a file name argument. Depending on what your application supports, you need to add one of the following field codes: `%f`, `%F`, `%u` or `%U`. See the [Desktop Entry specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) for details on the differences between these field codes.

For example, your line could become:

```
Exec=/home/thinus/.local/share/LightBurn/LightBurn %f
```

After this change, it will be included in the "Select Application" dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I must admit that I did not understand half of what was explained in that article you referred me too but I went with %F and it did the job.  Not only does the app now show as an option in "Open With Other Application" but when I double click on the file it opens directly in Lightburn.

Comment: Thanks for this comment! I fixed the problem that Xournalpp appimage, when creates the .desktop file (located in /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/xournalpp.desktop) it didn't inserted the %f at the end of the Exec line. Assing %f fixes! :D